# How do I disable Sharp's Network scanning tool from startup?

Tags: windows-7, boot, windows-services

I have Sharp's Network Scanning tool installed on my system however since I rarely use the printer I'd rather not have this scanning tool running in my system tray always.  I can manually right-click the tool in my system tray and stop it and exit it but it will come back next time I startup my computer.  I believe the exe name is FtpServer.exe.  I tried looking in the Windows Services but I don't see anything name like "Network Scanning..", "Sharp..", or "Ftp.."

Also I looked in:

`C:\Users\myusername\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup`

and

`C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup`

and did not see anything
For reference, here's some sharp documentation (I could not find the answer in it):
http://www.sharp.eu/cps/rde/xbcr/documents/documents/om/34_ppc/NetworkScannerTool-LT_OM_User-Guide_GB.pdf

How can I disable this tool from running at startup?

Comment: Look in the Startup folder in the Start Menu or the HKCU or HKLM Run keys in the registry.

Comment: Have you looked in the Start Up menu in the System Configuration? (Run msconfig then choose Start Up tab)

Comment: @joeqwerty: updated question I did look in the startup folders, will check the other options

Comment: Aha @DuckDuckGoose I see 4 items there with the Manufacturer of "SHARP CORPORATION"

Comment: You can disable all those or what you're looking for might just be something along the line of "Status Monitor" or something.

Comment: You did check the startup tab in the task manager, right? There's an easy option to disable programs that would run at startup. Unless that's new to Windows 8. And uhm. You did look at the program's options, right? Because the vast majority of programs have that as an option.

Comment: @Ariane: where is the startup tab in the task manager? I only see "Applications, Processes, Services, Performance, Networking, and Users". I'm using windows 7.  I guess you must be referring to windows 8

Comment: @DuckDuckGoose thanks that seems to have done the trick

Comment: Glad to hear that, then you wouldnt mind if I post it as an answer and you can accept it as such.

Comment: @User, yeah, probably it's the new task manager from Windows 8. This thing is great. It shows you everything that is launched on startup, and even an evaluation of how much it slows your PC down on startup. If you're interested, well: https://www.google.ca/search?q=windows+8+task+manager+for+windows+7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run 'msconfig' then select the Start Up tab. There you should be able to check what you're looking for and disable it to not run on start up.

Answer (score 1):

What you are looking for is FtpServer.exe and SharpTray.exe, both of which run from HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\WoW6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run (at least, on a 64-bit system).  It's amazing what you will find running from that location--and none of that stuff shows up in the Startup node of the System Info tool (try using Autoruns from Sysinternals instead).

Answer (score 0):

For Windows 8 there is Startup tab in the Task Manager that allows you to disable/enable items that are set to load on startup